# The solution of the IVP $\dot{x}=F(t,x),\ x(0)=x_0$ exists on $(-\infty, +\infty)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Let $F\in C^1$ be bounded. Then the solution of the IVP
> $$\dot{x}=F(t,x),\ x(0)=x_0$$ exists on $(-\infty, +\infty)$.

I have no idea how to prove the proposition. The $F\in C^1$ condition seems strange and I do not know how to use it.

Comment: If $F\in C^1$ is bounded then $F$ is Lipschitz continuous, existence and uniqueness global theorem?

Comment: @inoc : that is wrong, that would only the true if $F$ is $C^1$-bounded.

Answer (score 0):

As $|F(t,x)|\le M$ for some $M<\infty$, you can conclude that for any solution $|y(t)-y_0|\le M\,|t-t_0|$ in its domain. As that gives finite values at all finite times, the solution can be extended without restriction, the maximal solution has $\Bbb R$ as domain.